# How to get the rows (based on timestamp) of the table that reached the last intent

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to find in some chatbot logs the users that reached the last intent, but I need the intent before that one.

i.e.
Table 1

| ID | Intent |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | last |
| 1 | first |
| 2 | first |
| 3 | second |
| 4 | last |
| 4 | second |
| 4 | first |

would need to get this

| ID | Intent |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | first |
| 4 | second |

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "intent before that one" unless a column specifies the ordering.  No ordering column, no "before".

Comment: the intent is referred as an interaction with the chatbot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach (note you need some column that define order of intents - in below example I assume `ts` as a timestamp column)

```
select id, prev_intent as intent
from (
    select *, lag(intent) over(partition by id order by ts) prev_intent
    from `project.dataset.table`    
)
where intent = 'last'
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]